# Failed to execute flutter run

Tags: ios, flutter

When I do a flutter run it takes a long time and it doesn't work.
In the console I have this feedback

```
[   +3 ms] complete
[  +15 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
[  +14 ms] /Users/baayfalltakkjokk/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
/Users/baayfalltakkjokk/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
/Users/baayfalltakkjokk/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
--experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill
/var/folders/dm/zbkg8jzx6k56kcqw1h4n8rtm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.2vElno/flutter_tool.hqvxej/app.dill --packages
/Users/baayfalltakkjokk/Documents/PROJETS/Zonit_v1.0.0/client_zonit/.dart_tool/package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill
build/c075001b96339384a97db4862b8ab8db.cache.dill.track.dill --enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
[  +24 ms] executing: [/Users/baayfalltakkjokk/Documents/PROJETS/Zonit_v1.0.0/client_zonit/ios/] xcrun xcodebuild -list
[  +43 ms] <- compile package:zonit/main.dart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running with internet connection if not solved open terminal and run flutter doctor that will help you figure if you are missing something or not sir

Answer (score 0):

in TERMINAL run flutter doctor , He will fix the problem for you